# Quick way to bypass proxy with DownThemAll

Tags: firefox, proxy, firefox-extensions, download-manager, socks-proxy

I've been using an SSH proxy to my home network to encrypt my internet surfing, which is fine.  But the connection is much slower than the direct one, and when I'm downloading large files I'd rather go around the proxy.  Currently, I send it to Downthemall, go to FoxyProxy and disable the proxy, cancel and resume the download, then when it's started go back to FoxyProxy and re-enable it.  Is there any way I can just get DownThemAll stuff to skip the foxyproxy?

Answer (score 2):

How about using FoxyProxy [patterns](http://getfoxyproxy.org/patterns.html) to blacklist extensions of files that you commonly download?  Something like:

```
*.zip
*.rar
*.tgz
*.tar.gz
```